# How to use FINDSTR to filter text and produce a CSV file with specific data?

Tags: windows, findstr

My goal is to search `file.txt` to find an identifying string and then output the following words between the quotation marks.

So the identifier would be `data-default-alt=` and the name of the item is `"Ford Truck"` in quotes. I would like to output the name of the item and the price so that I can open it in Excel.

```
data-default-alt="Ford Truck"></h3></a></div><div class="tileInfo"><div class="swatchesBox--empty"></div><div class="promo-msg-text"><span class="calloutMsg-promo-msg-text"></span></div><div class="pricecontainer" data-pricetype="Stand Alone"><p id="price_206019013" class="price price-label ">$1,000.00</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `findstr` is what you want to use for this. You want an actual XML parser.

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions on how I should proceed